# Precedence of Azure AppService settings?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

My .NET Core 6 app service has the following setup inside `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//builder.Services.AddSingleton... ETC...
var app = builder.Build();
```

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), it has a default precedence in case of different sources:

1. Command-line arguments
2. Non-prefixed environment variables
3. User secrets
4. appsettings.{Environment}.jsonappsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json.
5. appsettings.json

But I don't see if they mention where `AppService` settings from the Azure portal configuration get applied.

I expect that Azure portal settings for "MyKey1" would override any of the previous, but it is not happening.

Let's say, I have a appsettings.json with:

```
{ MyKey1 : "Value1" }
```

and, in Azure site config:

```
MyKey1................Value2
```

When I deploy the app to the cloud it takes Value1 instead of Value2, for MyKey1.

Is this the normal behavior? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if that’s intentional that your keys are named differently?! MyKey and MyKey1 - of course they will complement each other, not overwrite

Comment: @silent, sorry, I have updated it. Both keys are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[App Settings get injected as Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings). So I would assume they fall into position 2 of your list.

Comment: Thanks. At the end, it was a typo between the l and 1 characters. In Prod, it was wrongly added as MyKeyL instead of MyKey1 (Real name of "MyKey" is different), which was incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. The documentation says that settings providers added later take priority. I think the actual behavior in Azure is that it will overwrite appsettings. Gonna get one of my engineers to test this..

This is the behavior in .net classic, not as sure about .net core...